# Can Python's map function call object member functions?

Tags: python

I need to do something that is functionally equivalent to this:

```
for foo in foos:
    bar = foo.get_bar()
    # Do something with bar
```

My first instinct was to use `map`, but this did not work:

```
for bar in map(get_bar, foos):
    # Do something with bar
```

Is what I'm trying to accomplish possible with `map`? Do I need to use a list comprehension instead? What is the most Pythonic idiom for this?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use a list comprehension?

Comment: @agf Because list comprehensions are for creating lists, not just calling a function on each element of a sequence.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Either with `lambda`:

```
for bar in map(lambda foo: foo.get_bar(), foos):
```

Or simply with instance method reference on your instance's class:

```
for bar in map(Foo.get_bar, foos):
```

As this was added from a comment, I would like to note that this requires the items of `foos` to be instances of `Foo` (i.e. `all(isinstance(foo, Foo) for foo in foos)` must be true) and not only as the other options do instances of classes with a `get_bar` method. This alone might be reason enough to not include it here.

Or with `methodcaller`:

```
import operator
get_bar = operator.methodcaller('get_bar')
for bar in map(get_bar, foos):
```

Or with a generator expression:

```
for bar in (foo.get_bar() for foo in foos):
```

Comment: In reverse order of how Pythonic they are.

Comment: Also, `map(Foo.get_bar, foos)` where `Foo` is the class of the objects in `foos`.

Comment: I decided to go with the lambda since I realised that I needed to do this transformation a couple places in the code, and `Bar`s needed to be stringified and lowercased. :)

Comment: @Dan D. : What if an argument needs to be passed into get_bar() such as get_bar(val) ?

Comment: @Spade I know this is late, but maybe it will help others.  Two ways to do this: 1) use a the variable val defined in a higher level scope (within the method defining the lambda or globally).  Typically this would act as a constant per comprehension.  Alternatively if you have a known sequence of parameters you can zip the objects and parameters together and use a lambda to pick out the object and parameter like this -- `lambda xy: xy[0].get_bar(xy[1])` the `foos` would instead be `xys = zip(foos,parameters)`.  This can get ugly and a helper function or alternate design may be better.

Comment: I hate the use of "foo" and "bar" which are deliberately chosen because of their meaningless. Why not "mthd" and "obj" or something?

Comment: @weemattisnot That is what the question used. If the question didn't have an example, one could freely choose better names.

Answer (score 11):

You want [`operator.methodcaller()`](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller). Or, of course, a list or generator comprehension.

Comment: I guess list comprehensions are preferred in newer versions of Python, right? I'll be happy to accept your answer if you update it to include sample code using an LC for my example. :)

Comment: @JoshGlover "newer versions of Python"? They go back to at least 2.3.

Comment: List comprehensions were added in Python 2.0.

Answer (score 6):

I think the cleanest way is to forgo the `for`-loop completely and use a list comprehension:

```
bars = [foo.get_bar() for foo in foos]
```

This answer is close to some other answers but differs in that the list is actually returned and not used in the subsequent loop. Depending on what you do with `bars`, you may be able to use a list comprehension there to.

I don't think the `map` function with `lambdas` are particulary readable, besides the overhead for `map` is considerable.

Answer (score 2):

This modified code will work:

```
for bar in map(lambda f: f.get_bar(), foos):
# Do something with bar
```

You provide lambda function here. Simply providing `get_bar` doesn't work because it is accessible only through an instance of class (`f.get_bar()`), never by itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *lambda*

```
for bar in map(lambda foo: foo.get_bar(), foos):
    # Do something with bar
```