# call member functions and pass arguments with map function in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Based on what I see in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7750982/can-pythons-map-function-call-object-member-functions) post, I tried to write this piece of code but it gives me error.

```
ticklabels = ax.get_xticklabels()
set_color = operator.methodcaller('set_color("b")')
ticklabels[0].set_color('b') # this runs fine
map(set_color, ticklabels)   #error is here
```

Error code:

> map(set_color, ticklabels) AttributeError: 'Text' object has no
>   attribute 'set_color("b")'

Can't you pass argument to the function in methodcaller?

Comment: Does `map(lambda x:x.set_color, ticklabels)` work?

Comment: @halex, yes your code also works and it is mentioned in the referred post. I just did not want to use `lambda`. Thanks for mentioning that.

Comment: The `lambda` variant should be `map(lambda x: x.set_color('b'), ticklabels)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need:

```
set_color = operator.methodcaller('set_color', 'b')
```

The first argument is the method to be called, subsequent arguments will be passed to the method when it is called.

You can then test it works by doing:

```
set_color(ticklabels[0])
```

Comment: Yes, did not read the documentation for the `methodcaller`. It is mentioned there.